# capacity management tool

Tags: open-source, prediction

We are an IT company which is using huge resource of storage & other devices.
There are scenario when suddenly we are informed that the usage of some devices or storage are fully consumed, So its impossible to raise a request & get the new resource available and configure it for customer. This process takes lots of time & approvals.

Is there any opensource tool which can access the daily usage database and show future consumption of the resource usage.